# AWS IoT built-in functions with Terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, aws-iot

Quick question regarding `IoT` rules and `Terraform` :

I'm trying to create `"aws_iot_topic_rule"` resource, how can I interact with `IoT` built-in functions like `topic` ?

`topic()` docs - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-function-topic

Something like :

```
resource "aws_iot_topic_rule" "rule" {
 ...

 kafka {
    ...
    key = "${sha1(topic(3))}"
  }
}
```

When trying something like that I get a `Terraform` error saying `There is no function named "topic".`

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, having key as `"$${sha1(topic(3))}"` did the trick

([terraform strings interpolation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings))